# How to split text in more than one column simultaneously

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which I keep a whole load of information about the text I am interested in (parts of speech mainly). The data is kept in the same format as the original text it is extracted for (each part of speech is semi-colon separated and each sentence is separated by a newline.

I want to query the parts of speech sometimes for different things, like getting a sentence that has `NOUN PUNCT NOUN NOUN NOUN` in sequence and then all lines that have this to the dataframe and a further column that tells me the text that this relates to. I want to get the same data for the `head_token_id`.

I guess I have to convert the newlines into a list, get the index of any line that shows me a match for a regular expression search and then retrieve the same index in neighbouring columns but I dont know how to do this. My data structure is below with some fake data:

**Data**

```
  structure(list(sentence = c(",\n,Biopsies taken from top of stricture-metal marking clips in situ.\n,Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm .,She has a small hiatus hernia .\nDr. Martin, Marche Date of procedure: 2009-11-11 Endoscopist:\nDr. Sullivan, Shelby Second endoscopist: Dr. al-Basha, Mahfoodha Medications:\nExtent of Exam: GOJ Indications: Follow-up ULCER HEALING Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings:\nFentanyl 12.5mcg Midazolam 6mg Instrument: FG5\nHALO 90 done with good effect Endoscopic Diagnosis:\nHe is on Barrett's Screeling List in October 2017 at St Thomas'.\nHospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: J6044658\nNo evidence of Barrett's oesophagus, short 2 cn hiatus hernia.\n,Oesophageal biopsies taken from three levels as requested.\n,OGD today to assess for ulceration/ongoing bleeding.\nPatient Name: Jargon, Victoria General Practitioner:\nPost chemo-radiotherapy stricture\n,The varices flattened well with air insufflation.\nTiny erosions at the antrum.\nWe will re-book for 2 weeks, rebanding.", 
"Date of procedure: 2008-06-15 Endoscopist:\nDr. al-Safi, Lutfiyya\nDr. Kekich, Annabelle Second endoscopist: Dr. Needham, April Medications:\nDuodenitis with a small erosion .\nEndoscopic Diagnosis:\nEsophageal candidiasis\nExtent of Exam: Pylorus Indications: Weight Loss Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings: Duodenum:\nFentanyl 125mcg Midazolam 7mg Instrument: FG6\nHospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: Y6417773 Patient Name: Powell, Destiny General Practitioner:\n,STOMACH: diffuse gastritis with angiodysplasia and punctate bleeding site on greater curve mid body - no obvious ulcer- antrum scar ?,No immediate complications.\n,Z-line at: 38cm - Bravo placed at 32cm- good positionat check endoscopy."
), HospitalNumber = c(" J6044658\n", " Y6417773\n"), upos = c("PUNCT;PUNCT;PUNCT\nPUNCT;AUX;VERB;ADP;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT\nPUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;PUNCT;PRON;VERB;DET;ADJ;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;DET;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM;SYM;NUM;SYM;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT\nNOUN;ADP;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;ADP;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;NOUN;PUNCT\nVERB;NUM;NOUN;PROPN;NUM;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM\nSYM;NUM;ADJ;ADP;ADJ;NOUN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nPRON;AUX;ADP;PROPN;PART;NOUN;NOUN;ADP;PROPN;NUM;ADP;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PUNCT\nNOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN\nDET;NOUN;ADP;PROPN;PART;NOUN;PUNCT;ADJ;NUM;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT\nPUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;VERB;ADP;NUM;NOUN;SCONJ;VERB;PUNCT\nVERB;NOUN;PART;VERB;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT\nADJ;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nVERB;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN\nPUNCT;DET;NOUN;VERB;ADV;ADP;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT\nDET;NOUN;ADP;DET;NOUN;PUNCT\nPRON;AUX;VERB;PUNCT;NOUN;ADP;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;VERB;PUNCT", 
"NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM;SYM;NUM;SYM;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT\nNOUN;ADP;DET;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nADJ;NOUN\nNOUN;ADP;PROPN;PUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;VERB;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT\nINTJ;VERB;PROPN;NUM;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM\nNOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nPUNCT;VERB;PUNCT;VERB;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;CCONJ;VERB;VERB;NOUN;ADP;ADJ;NOUN;X;NOUN;PUNCT;DET;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT;PUNCT;DET;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT\nADJ;PUNCT;NOUN;ADP;PUNCT;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;VERB;ADP;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT"
), head_token_id = c("0;0;0\n3;3;0;5;3;11;9;9;11;11;5;13;11;3\n5;3;5;5;9;5;9;9;0;13;13;13;9;9\n0;1;1;5;1;7;5;1;14;11;9;9;14;1;1\n0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;8;8;8;8;8;1;1\n0;3;1;1;6;1;6;10;10;6;13;13;20;13;14;14;18;14;18;6;1\n0;3;7;3;6;7;1;1;1\n3;1;0;8;6;8;8;3;3\n7;7;7;7;4;7;0;9;7;9;13;13;7;13;7\n0;1;6;3;3;7;1;7;7;7\n2;0;6;6;4;2;2;11;10;11;12;2;2\n3;3;0;3;7;7;4;9;4;3\n0;1;4;1;6;4;9;9;6;1\n2;0;2;8;4;4;4;2;2\n0;4;4;5;1\n4;3;4;0;4;8;8;4;4\n2;0;5;5;2;2\n3;3;0;5;3;8;8;5;3;3;3", 
"0;3;1;1;1;7;5;9;7;1;10\n0;1;1;1;1;1\n0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;8;1;12;1;1\n0;5;5;5;1;1\n0;1;1\n2;0\n0;3;1;1;6;1;6;10;10;6;17;13;11;15;13;13;1;17;17;17\n2;0;6;3;6;2;2;2\n0;1;6;3;3;7;1;1;12;12;12;8;12;12;18;18;16;14;1\n2;0;2;2;4;7;5;9;4;9;10;16;14;16;16;10;2;23;23;22;22;23;2;2;2;28;28;2;2\n3;3;9;7;7;7;3;7;10;0;18;13;15;15;16;18;18;10;10"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired output if I am looking for `NOUN PUNCT NOUN NOUN NOUN` (joined with the original dataframe)

```
Match_sentence
1. ",Biopsies taken from top of stricture-metal marking clips in situ."
2. "Extent of Exam: Pylorus Indications: Weight Loss Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings: Duodenum:"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do that with `data.table` and `grepl`. This will give you the two records you are looking for.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[grepl("NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;",upos)]
```

Using a `data.frame,` this works:

```
df[grepl("NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;",df$upos),]
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(sentence = c(",\n,Biopsies taken from top of stricture-metal marking clips in situ.\n,Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm .,She has a small hiatus hernia .\nDr. Martin, Marche Date of procedure: 2009-11-11 Endoscopist:\nDr. Sullivan, Shelby Second endoscopist: Dr. al-Basha, Mahfoodha Medications:\nExtent of Exam: GOJ Indications: Follow-up ULCER HEALING Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings:\nFentanyl 12.5mcg Midazolam 6mg Instrument: FG5\nHALO 90 done with good effect Endoscopic Diagnosis:\nHe is on Barrett's Screeling List in October 2017 at St Thomas'.\nHospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: J6044658\nNo evidence of Barrett's oesophagus, short 2 cn hiatus hernia.\n,Oesophageal biopsies taken from three levels as requested.\n,OGD today to assess for ulceration/ongoing bleeding.\nPatient Name: Jargon, Victoria General Practitioner:\nPost chemo-radiotherapy stricture\n,The varices flattened well with air insufflation.\nTiny erosions at the antrum.\nWe will re-book for 2 weeks, rebanding.", 
                            "Date of procedure: 2008-06-15 Endoscopist:\nDr. al-Safi, Lutfiyya\nDr. Kekich, Annabelle Second endoscopist: Dr. Needham, April Medications:\nDuodenitis with a small erosion .\nEndoscopic Diagnosis:\nEsophageal candidiasis\nExtent of Exam: Pylorus Indications: Weight Loss Procedure Performed: Gastroscopy (OGD) Findings: Duodenum:\nFentanyl 125mcg Midazolam 7mg Instrument: FG6\nHospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust Hospital Number: Y6417773 Patient Name: Powell, Destiny General Practitioner:\n,STOMACH: diffuse gastritis with angiodysplasia and punctate bleeding site on greater curve mid body - no obvious ulcer- antrum scar ?,No immediate complications.\n,Z-line at: 38cm - Bravo placed at 32cm- good positionat check endoscopy."
), HospitalNumber = c(" J6044658\n", " Y6417773\n"), upos = c("PUNCT;PUNCT;PUNCT\nPUNCT;AUX;VERB;ADP;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT\nPUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;PUNCT;PRON;VERB;DET;ADJ;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;DET;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM;SYM;NUM;SYM;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT\nNOUN;ADP;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;ADP;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;NOUN;PUNCT\nVERB;NUM;NOUN;PROPN;NUM;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM\nSYM;NUM;ADJ;ADP;ADJ;NOUN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nPRON;AUX;ADP;PROPN;PART;NOUN;NOUN;ADP;PROPN;NUM;ADP;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PUNCT\nNOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN\nDET;NOUN;ADP;PROPN;PART;NOUN;PUNCT;ADJ;NUM;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT\nPUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;VERB;ADP;NUM;NOUN;SCONJ;VERB;PUNCT\nVERB;NOUN;PART;VERB;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT\nADJ;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nVERB;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN\nPUNCT;DET;NOUN;VERB;ADV;ADP;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT\nDET;NOUN;ADP;DET;NOUN;PUNCT\nPRON;AUX;VERB;PUNCT;NOUN;ADP;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;VERB;PUNCT", 
                                                              "NOUN;ADP;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM;SYM;NUM;SYM;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;NOUN;PUNCT\nNOUN;ADP;DET;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT\nPROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nADJ;NOUN\nNOUN;ADP;PROPN;PUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;VERB;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT\nINTJ;VERB;PROPN;NUM;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT;NUM\nNOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PUNCT;PROPN;PROPN;PROPN;PUNCT\nPUNCT;VERB;PUNCT;VERB;NOUN;ADP;NOUN;CCONJ;VERB;VERB;NOUN;ADP;ADJ;NOUN;X;NOUN;PUNCT;DET;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT;PUNCT;DET;ADJ;NOUN;PUNCT\nADJ;PUNCT;NOUN;ADP;PUNCT;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;PROPN;VERB;ADP;NUM;NOUN;PUNCT;ADJ;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;PUNCT"
), head_token_id = c("0;0;0\n3;3;0;5;3;11;9;9;11;11;5;13;11;3\n5;3;5;5;9;5;9;9;0;13;13;13;9;9\n0;1;1;5;1;7;5;1;14;11;9;9;14;1;1\n0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;8;8;8;8;8;1;1\n0;3;1;1;6;1;6;10;10;6;13;13;20;13;14;14;18;14;18;6;1\n0;3;7;3;6;7;1;1;1\n3;1;0;8;6;8;8;3;3\n7;7;7;7;4;7;0;9;7;9;13;13;7;13;7\n0;1;6;3;3;7;1;7;7;7\n2;0;6;6;4;2;2;11;10;11;12;2;2\n3;3;0;3;7;7;4;9;4;3\n0;1;4;1;6;4;9;9;6;1\n2;0;2;8;4;4;4;2;2\n0;4;4;5;1\n4;3;4;0;4;8;8;4;4\n2;0;5;5;2;2\n3;3;0;5;3;8;8;5;3;3;3", 
                     "0;3;1;1;1;7;5;9;7;1;10\n0;1;1;1;1;1\n0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;8;1;12;1;1\n0;5;5;5;1;1\n0;1;1\n2;0\n0;3;1;1;6;1;6;10;10;6;17;13;11;15;13;13;1;17;17;17\n2;0;6;3;6;2;2;2\n0;1;6;3;3;7;1;1;12;12;12;8;12;12;18;18;16;14;1\n2;0;2;2;4;7;5;9;4;9;10;16;14;16;16;10;2;23;23;22;22;23;2;2;2;28;28;2;2\n3;3;9;7;7;7;3;7;10;0;18;13;15;15;16;18;18;10;10"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am looking to get the output specified in the question. This just gives me the two whole records back. Have I missed something?

Comment: You need to clean up your data first. . The multi-sentence entries in `upos` must be in separate entries (probably using split on the `/n` character). then you can use `df[grepl("NOUN;PUNCT;NOUN;NOUN;NOUN;",df$upos),]`